# cv2 convert Range and copyTo functions of c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

I'm writing a python video stabilizer and in some part of the code i need to copy 2 images into a canvas.

I tried to convert this c++ code to python but i wasn't able.

```
Mat cur2;

warpAffine(cur, cur2, T, cur.size());

cur2 = cur2(Range(vert_border, cur2.rows-vert_border), 
Range(HORIZONTAL_BORDER_CROP, cur2.cols-HORIZONTAL_BORDER_CROP));

// Resize cur2 back to cur size, for better side by side comparison
resize(cur2, cur2, cur.size());

// Now draw the original and stablised side by side for coolness
Mat canvas = Mat::zeros(cur.rows, cur.cols*2+10, cur.type());

cur.copyTo(canvas(Range::all(), Range(0, cur2.cols)));
cur2.copyTo(canvas(Range::all(), Range(cur2.cols+10, cur2.cols*2+10)));
```

I wrote this code but i got error:

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
new_frame = transform(frame,data[counter]) #some kind of low pass filter

canvas = np.zeros ((frame_height, frame_width*2+10,3))
np.copyto (canvas[:frame_width], frame)
np.copyto (canvas[frame_width+10:frame_width*2+10], new_frame)
```

I got

> "couldnt boradcast from shape into shape"

err. But i think i used canvas in wrong way. in cpp code there is `canvas(Range::all(), Range(0, cur2.cols))` which i dont know how to use it in python

How can i use Range function and copyTo function in python?
And how should i copy an image to a specific part of canvas?

Any help?

Comment: _I wrote this code but i got error:_ Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I got "couldnt boradcast from shape into shape" err. But i think i used canvas in wrong way. in cpp code there is canvas(Range::all(), Range(0, cur2.cols)) which i dont know how to use it in python !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cv::Mat are actually numpy arrays in python. And in this case, you should use numpy functions and not OpenCV ones.

For the copyTo as clone, use copy() as in:

```
a = np.zeros((10,10,3), dtype=np.uint8)
b = a.copy()
```

For ranges, in numpy is easier... just use:

```
a[y1:y2, x1:x2,:]
```

which means from row y1 to row y2 and from column x1 to column x2. In case you need all, just leave the `:` alone like all rows:

```
a[:, x1:x2,:]
```

The last colon is for channels, in this case all channels, but you can also limit it. And if you need only 1 column, or channel you can put the number directly instead of using a "range" like

```
a[4, x1:x2, 0]
```

You can also drop the last colon of the channels, and it will use all of them. Like:

```
a[1:3, 4:8]
```

Finally, to copy a value to a place in the image you can do something like:

```
bigImage[y1:y2, x1:x2] =  image
```

You have to make sure that image fits in this place (channels included). That means, if image is of size 640x480 you can not do this:

```
bigImage[10:20, 20:30] =  image
```

but you can do something like

```
bigImage[10:20, 20:30] =  image[10:20, 10:20]
```

assuming both have the same number of channels